# jquery giving "invalid property value" error in Internet Explorer11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
        //jquery 2.1.0 code line no 7026 onward 

 if ( value !== undefined ) {
                    return hooks && "set" in hooks && (ret = hooks.set( elem, value, name )) !== undefined ?
                        ret :
                        ( elem[ name ] = value );  //here i am getting invalid property                value error

                } else {
                    return hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, name )) !== null ?
                        ret :
                        elem[ name ];
                }
```

**and when I made some changes in jQuery code  like this**

```
 if ( value !== undefined ) {
                if ( value === null ) {
                        jQuery.removeAttr( elem, name );

                    } else if ( hooks && notxml && "set" in hooks && (ret = hooks.set( elem, value, name )) !== undefined ) {
                        return ret;

                    } else {
                        elem.setAttribute( name, value + "" );
                        return value;
                    }

                } else if ( hooks && notxml && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, name )) !== null ) {
                    return ret;


                } else {
                    ret = elem.getAttribute( name );

                    // Non-existent attributes return null, we normalize to undefined
                    return ret == null ?
                        undefined :
                        ret;
                }
```

**then it is working fine but changes in jQuery library is not recommended so is there any other solution ? can we override jquery method if yes then how can we override?**

Comment: Something is causing that error, you have to fix what's causing it, not modify jQuery, and yes, I think this is a known [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/997939/ie11-imageelement-setattribute-fails-with-invalid-argument-when-key-is-src-and-value-has-a-percent)

Comment: thanks adeneo :) but same thing working in chrome

Comment: check this http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13011